# How to link .xml file to .kt file in Kotlin

Tags: xml, kotlin, debugging, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

My friend and I have coded two parts of our app separately and are now trying to join it together. I have coded the themes in a .xml document, while her code uses a .kt document for the theme. What would be the most efficient way of compiling them? Would it require any manual recoding/ is there a program that can achieve this online?

Here is my friend's code:

[image]

We tried adding the themes.xml onto her code, but this clearly did not work, since we do not know how to properly call it.